# Using array to pass through a find loop

Tags: excel, vba

here is my code, its almost working but only passes the first part of the array. I think its the second end if, but if i remove it. It says no next without for even though for for part is at the beginning of the loop. Can someone tell me what I did wrong please.

```
Sub findEG()
Dim rng, s, e As Range
Dim rws As Long, w As Long
Dim vWHATs As Variant

lastrow = Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

vWHATs = Array("LIFES - Sup Life - Sps", "LIFEE - Sup Life - Emp", "LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch", _
               "VLTD  - Vol LTD MOO", "VSTD  - Vol STD MOO")

With Worksheets("MOO Data")   
For w = LBound(vWHATs) To UBound(vWHATs)
Set r = .Range("B:B").Find(vWHATs)

      If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set e = .Range("B:B").Find("Totals for:", r)
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            .Range(r, e).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("A" & lastrow) 
        End If

      End If
Next w

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you expecting only one row returned?  as you have it if you expect multiples it is being over written each time as you do not iterate off `lastrow`

Comment: are you getting an error?  What is this code supposed to do, and what exactly is happening?  Is there data on the worksheet?  If so, please share a sample of that too.  Also, Welcome! Check out the [tour] and [mcve].

Comment: It looks for range R and E, and then copies the values between them. right now the code is just finding the first case and thats it, i need the other 5 with the E variable as "totals for:" at the end of it to be copied also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code below and I believe it does what you want it to do:

```
Sub findEG()
Dim rng, s As Range
Dim rws As Long, w As Long
Dim vWHATs As Variant
lastrow = Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

vWHATs = Array("LIFES - Sup Life - Sps", "LIFEE - Sup Life - Emp", "LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch", _
               "VLTD  - Vol LTD MOO", "VSTD  - Vol STD MOO")

With Worksheets("MOO Data")
For w = LBound(vWHATs) To UBound(vWHATs)
Set r = .Range("B:B").Find(vWHATs(w)) 'included the (w) so the array values go in sequence in the For Loop
      If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set e = .Range("B:B").Find("Totals for:" & r.Value & "*") ' here are you sure you are looking for the possible string: "Totals for:LIFES - Sup Life - Sps" without the space between the :?
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            .Rows(r.Row & ":" & e.Row).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("A" & lastrow +1)
        End If

      End If
Next w
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: here is the original code.. it looks for the values between R and E and copies them. The above code found the next string but the the values between the new R and E ranges..   Dim s As Range, e As Range
With Sheet1 'or this can be any other sheet where you search
    Set r = .Range("B:B").Find("LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set e = .Range("B:B").Find("Totals for:", r)
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            .Range(r, e).EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1") 'or to whatever sheet
        End If
    End If
End With


End Sub

Comment: @ChristopherPieper Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: it is more like this sir

LIFES - Sup Life - Sps 
123
123
321
Totals for:

Something else - d
123
123
123
Totals For:

VSTD  - Vol STD MOO
123 
123
Totals for:

And I am trying to copy the data between the two ranges to a new sheet

Comment: What is the 123 123 321? is that in the same cell as the "Totals for:"? If this is the case then I've updated my answer to find "Totals For: LIFES - Sup Life - Sps" and any other value after that...

Comment: I'm pretty sure, actually I've tested it too, this should work, unless there are other things at play, such as the contents of the cells might not match your search criteria, but apart from a little tweaking, this should do what you wanted, please could you mark my response as an answer?

Comment: it doesn't, but I appreciate your time, I ended up running it as different functions. This code works fine for one, i just needed it for the other 5 cases. 
Dim s As Range, e As Range
lastrow = Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("MOO Data")
    Set r = .Range("B:B").Find("VSTD  - Vol STD MOO")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set e = .Range("B:E").Find("Totals for:", r)
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            .Range(r, e).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("MOO_filtered").Range("A" & lastrow)
        End If
    End If
End With ..